# what is the name of the font given in the image?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image]

i had tried to find this font in many web pages but couldn't find the exact font.So please can somebody help me to find this font.

Comment: Looks a bit like [Dax](http://www.myfonts.com/search/Dax/fonts/) -- it isn't, but that might be a reasonable font to substitute if necessary.

Comment: thank you Andrew but i need the exact font

Comment: If you are not Johan, it's rather impolite to post his email publicly. I've edited the image to remove a portion to help protect Johan from unsolicited emails.

Comment: one which looks very similar Amor Sans Text http://www.identifont.com/samples/storm/AmorSansTextPro.gif

Comment: @Scott there is no even such domain named "creativethoughtgroup.com", consequently, the email adress *****@domainNameinQuestion does not exist at all....

Comment: Still bad form, Ilan.

Answer (score 4):

This font called Cuprum. It is available for free from [Google fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Cuprum)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks very similar to [Guarda Sans Regular](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/konstantynov/guarda-sans/regular/) or a vertically stretched variant of [Soleto Regular](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/daltonmaag/soleto/regular/).

Answer (score 0):

In the future, give this tool a shot (http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) it's been helpful time and time again for font matching.  I would say it's more-or-less 90% accurate.